# Javascript choose from input suggestions

Tags: javascript, html, web, radio-button

I'm trying to create a search box to search for colleges inside the united states. For now I'm using a hard coded set of colleges, but what I'm asking about is I want the user to start searching, when suggestions show up. Then the user must choose from one of the suggestions rather than being able to look for "aksdbg", because such a college does not exist. Basically what I'm doing is a radio button list, but the list is too long for me to list all the colleges for the user to choose from. Thanks

Comment: What's your question exactly, where did you get stuck when you tried to make this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This post doesn’t seem like it has a specific question. If im not wrong, it is asking for a tutorial/guide or suggestions on how to implement a specific feature. Which unfortunately is not really suitable to ask here, askers here are encouraged to include a [mre] and show us the issues they are facing while attempting it. You can check out the [ask] section of Stack Overflow for more info. Goodluck :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not be understanding you correctly but I believe jQueryUI does exactly what you are asking with ease. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Auto-complete will let you hard-code those terms and as people search will display matches.

Comment: thanks! sorry yeah, i just didn't know how to formulate the question